In s/fscanf(), how to ensure that the entire format string was matched against entire input?
The *scanf() family of functions return the number of "input items" (that is, conversion specifications) successfully matched and assigned:

RETURN VALUE
On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Now, consider a format string that contains some conversion specifications interleaved with some literal characters and ends in one or more literal characters:
// read the response to a CSI 14 t request
int r = sscanf(input, "\033[4;%d;%dt", &resp_y, &resp_x);

Consider four potential inputs to this sscanf call:

"\033[4;100;200t"
"\033[4;100;200"
"\033[4;100;200foobar"
"\033[4;100;200tfoobar"

As far as I can understand, in this case the return value (r) will be set to 2 in all three cases. However, only input (1) is valid, while inputs (2) and (3) are invalid, and input (4) contains trailing data.

What is the cleanest / most correct way to distinguish (1) from (2) and (3) and from (4), i.e. ensure that the entire format string was successfully matched against the entire input?
I'm interested in answers to this question for both sscanf() and fscanf().

sscanf (and its siblings) is a very blunt instrument for string parsing and validation. If you need more advanced validation then you need to create your own parser to parse the specific string.

Your title mentions scanf but your example uses sscanf. What constitutes the “entire input” differs for these, including whether, for scanf, you want to consider the entire input to be the entire stream until end-of-file or just one entire line entered by the user or something else. For sscanf, you can use %n at the end to get the number of characters read and compare it to the length of the string. For scanf, you can use getchar afterward to see if the next character is a newline or if EOF is returned, as desired, and, if desired, use ungetc to put the character back.

So, edit the question to clarify whether you are asking for sscanf from a string or scanf from a stream and what you consider the “entire input” to be.

@EricPostpischil The second word of the question indicates that they're asking about the scanf family, not one specific function.

@Barmar: (a) It discusses the *scanf family as background/introductory information. It does not say they are asking about the entire family. (b) The issue remains different for sscanf and scanf. The question ought to be narrowed. At the very list, OP needs to clarify if they want to ask about one, the other, or actually about both.

As @Someprogrammerdude mentioned, *scanf is the wrong tool.  But maybe you can just replace the t at the end of the format string with %c and then check both the return value and verify that it copied a t into the target. (Then the string ending 200toobar will also match, so you need to add more logic, and in the end you stop using scanf anyway.)

@EricPostpischil Good catch. My immediate question was about sscanf(), but I'd also be interested in an answer to the equivalent question for fscanf().

Use:
int n = 0;
int r = sscanf(input, "\033[4;%d;%dt%n", &resp_y, &resp_x, &n);
if (r != 2 || n == 0)
{
    …scanning failed…
}

Note that the assignment to n is not counted as a 'conversion' so it isn't counted in the return value.
If you want to ensure that the whole string was used with sscanf(), then you can check:
if (r == 2 && n != 0 && input[n] == '\0')
{
   …whole string was scanned…
}

This technique using %n can be used with any of the scanf() family of functions.  Although I've linked to POSIX documentation, the C standard says the same things.  If you're reading from a file (fscanf() or scanf() rather than sscanf()), you probably don't want to check the value of n more than shown in the first snippet.  If you want to test for a newline (or other white space), you can't do that so easily with scanf() — see What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?.

Shouldn't it be n != strlen(input)?

Thanks, I was only vaguely aware of %n and didn't think to use it that way. However I also wonder about the "entire input" part of the question.

@Barmar: it depends on what you want.  If the t is missing, %n won't be processed, so it will be left at 0.  If you want nothing left over with sscanf() et al, then n != strlen(input) would check that all characters in the string are processed.  You could also use if (input[n] != '\0') of course.  With the file-based scanf() functions, you probably don't want to do a length check like that; there could be more data in the file after what was scanned.

It's what the OP says they want. Example #3 is supposed to fail because it has foobar at the end of the input.

Ah, I think I misunderstood because I didn't see the t in their format string.

@Barmar Good catch as well, I'm also interested in detecting trailing data (as per the title). I've edited the question and this answer to add my understanding of the fscanf() equivalent.

@intelfx: I rolled back your changes because they overrode my changes addressing the same issues.  I'm not planning to edit again for a while, so if you still want to include some portion of your edit into my current answer, you can do so safely.

@JonathanLeffler Could you clarify what exactly do you mean by "testing for trailing whitespace"?

@intelfx: see the linked question (about trailing white space).  Putting a blank, tab or newline at the end of a scanf() — as opposed to sscanf() — format string is a bad idea (especially if the input is coming from a user typing at the terminal).  WIth sscanf(), it is less problematic, but still not what you usually want.  The scanf() family of functions are hard to use correctly — there is some wisdom in avoiding them, as suggested in the comments to the question.  See also Beginner's Guide Away From scanf().

@JonathanLeffler I read the linked question before asking. The question still stands. Clearly, if we are talking about "the whole input", we are not dealing with interactive input.

Which part of the second code fragment is unclear about checking "the whole input"?

Akin to @Jonathan Leffler good answer.
Use " %n" to record the offset of the scan.
Not only use "%n", consider " %n" to first consume 0 or more whitespaces.  This is useful as input often has a potential trailing '\n' (maybe coming form fgets() ) and a format " " eliminates the need for input to have trailing white-space, like '\n', stripped off.  This allows the scan offset saved to be the end-of-the-line.
Code can also check r == 2 belt and suspenders, yet that is not needed as n will only be non-zero if r == 2.
Note: matching a "%n" does not contribute to the return value.
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stream)) {
  // No need to strip off  potential trailing white-space.

  // int r = sscanf(input, "\033[4;%d;%dt", &resp_y, &resp_x);
  int n = 0;
  int r = sscanf(input, "\033[4;%d;%dt %n", &resp_y, &resp_x, &n);
  if (n) success();
  else fail();
}


To make certain that all of input was used, also test that input[n] is a null character.
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stream)) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(input, "\033[4;%d;%dt %n", &resp_y, &resp_x, &n);
  if (n && input[n] == '\0') success();
  else fail();
}

